# Multiple launchs in terminal

Tags: kinect, openni, turtlebot, multiple, threads

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I'm running experiments in my project using turtlebot and kinect but i'd like to improve the speed of that by launching all the .launch files once for each experiment. Is that possible?

For example, i need to run `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch, roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch, roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch,` etc...

I know that for each terminal the bashrc is initialized, so running this in multiple terminals could be a problem (i guess).
Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209794/multiple-launchs-in-terminal/) by [Phelipe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21088/phelipe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2015-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend creating a single launch file which includes the other launch files.  You can use the [include tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/include)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4